# how can we apply validation in a jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have written the following code but its not working. Can you please help me.
Though these solutions are available everywhere but still the code is not working.

```
<div align="center">Registration Form</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {
            var name = document.myform.name.value;
            var password = document.myform.password.value;
            var email = document.myform.email.value;
            var mobile = document.myform.mobile.value;

            if(name.equals(""))
            {
                alert("Enter name");
                return false;
            }
            else if(password.equals(""))
            {
                alert("Enter password");
                return false;
            }
            else if(email.equals(""))
            {
                alert("Enter email-id");
                return false;
            }
            else if(mobile.equals(""))
            {
                alert("Enter mobile no.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Submitted");
                return true;
            }
        }
        </script>
<body>
    <form name ="myform" method="post" onsubmit = "return validate()">
```

Comment: None of these is working. When I run the page on web browser none of the message is displayed

Answer (score 1):

JS String does not have method/prototype `.equals()`.

Seems like you have mistaken with Java's `String#equals()`. Replace your code `name.equals("")` with `name === ""`  instead or just `name.length === 0` and so on for the rest.

For debugging purpose keep open developer console open, from browser press F12, there you will get those errors.

Comment: @Nabiha, can you share few print screen of the page rendered by browser before and after form submit, capturing browser console as well, also make sure that javascript is not disabled.

Comment: @Nabiha, that link is not public link, are you trying to make me laugh?